# How do I get Visual Studio 2019 Community back to my Azure DevOps projects

Tags: visual-studio-2019, azure-devops

We use the MS hosted Azure DevOps (in a TFS-style repository). For years, I've been rocking along just fine. But a couple of months ago, I started getting unusually frequent prompts to re-enter credentials...which devolved into an error that ended in "unexpected error on send" (I dearly wish I had the complete error message now.) On this, I could refresh repeatedly...typically 3 or 4 times...until it finally let me do whatever I was trying to do (compare, check-out, check in, get latest, etc.)

In an attempt to clear this state, I found threads that suggested getting rid of %localappdata%/.IdentityService...which I did. *That was probably a bad idea.* It didn't help...and in fact ultimately led to a state where it tells me I don't have access to perform the operation. Refreshing worked a couple of times...but not any more.

So, next step was to completely uninstall/re-install Visual Studio 2019 Community (with a reboot in between and then after installation). Now, when I attempt to set a connection to the project, the connect dialog found the servers I have used in the past, and I'm offered the servers, but no projects show up underneath. There are actually two team projects therein...and of course, until I pick a project, the connect button never lights up.

I have another computer...on the same wireless LAN connected to a Verizon mifi 2011 5g (not a corporate setting, btw), and on this second computer, everything works just fine...with the same MS account, too! Both computers connect to the internet just fine. Both computers allow me into the the web portals for the projects without complaint. Speedtest is reasonable from both machines. Other paywalled and cookie'd applications work as expected on both machines.

One strange "feature" of my account is that it's an MS account with a gmail address. That is, when I set up the account way back in the day, I used my xxx.yyy@gmail.com. It has a distinct password from my Google gmail account. I have noticed that as the logon dialog for VS itself flashes a xxxyyygmailcom@onmicrosoft.com. I would expect a mapping of some kind...so I don't know if this contributes to the problem in any way...as it works just perfectly on the second computer.

The failing machine is a Dell XPS 15 9570 laptop. The second is a Frankenstein desktop from parts from newegg. Both machines are Windows 10 Enterprise machines, and I keep them up to date with Windows Updates.

Answer (score 1):

For any poor soul that gets into this state, I figured I'd post what finally worked:

- Log out of VS
- Log out of all Microsoft accounts in all browsers and
  delete all MS related cookies...including Internet Explorer (which
  you might have *never ever* used).
- Make sure you have TLS 1.2
  explicitly enabled:

  HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client
  Enabled = 1

  (based on a closed [VS Community reported problem](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/team-foundation-add-in-throwing-error-message-tf40/446629) that said TLS 1.0...but it was 2 yrs old)
- Start VS - log in
- Connect to Team project (in team explorer's manage connection window)

There was an additional hardware/firmware-related error. Turns out, in this and similar models, there's a bug somewhere related to the battery power sensor that causes firmware to put your CPU in a low-power state, even when plugged in. You have to disconnect the battery for a minute or two, and the low power state clears up. This propagates to peripherals...and network operations time out frequently. It may have been the root cause.

Comment: I am not sure if this is error is generic enough to help someone else but if there is a chance to help one poor soul to fix this (quicker), I upvote.